# Oracle 11 Scheduled Jobs BROKEN?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduled-tasks

Oracle 11.2.0.3 - Scheduled jobs started showing up today as BROKEN. Nothing has changed in the schema since yesterday, and the job itself compiles fine.

I tried the steps at http://www.dba-oracle.com/dbms_job_broken.htm but that didn't help.

This is a production system, and I'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you delete the users/schemas that created the scheduled jobs? This happened to me this week. The DBA user that created the scheduled job was removed, and all of a sudden the jobs she had created were BROKEN.

Fix action was to recreate the scheduled jobs as the owning schema. Everything was fine after that.